# Why `exports` is referencing same object as `this` in nodejs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Today i found very strange way of using exports... This is code of separate nodejs module, that reproduces it.

Guys assign values to `this` scope, which is equal to `exports` variable. How do they achieved that `exports`=`this`?

```
(function() {

  this.Test = (function(){

    function Test() {
      this.name = 'Test 1';
    }

    return Test;

  })();

  // Will output Test { name: 'Test 1' }
  console.log(new exports.Test);

  // Will output { Test: [Function: Test] }
  console.log(exports);

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node, `exports` is very similar to the `window` object in the DOM where `window.foo` would be equivalent to `this.foo`, when used in the global scope.

In this case, `exports` is essentially `this` of the entire module. When you use `.call(this)`, you're essentially manually setting the `this` value of the anonymous function to the `this` value of the module, AKA the global scope object.

Thus, `this` in the call is referencing the global scope, the anonymous function is bound to the global `this`, and `exports` is equivalent to the global `this`.

You code is equivalent to this:

```
this.Test = (function(){

  function Test() {
    this.name = 'Test 1';
  }

  return Test;
})();

// Will output Test { name: 'Test 1' }
console.log(new exports.Test);

// Will output { Test: [Function: Test] }
console.log(exports);
```